# how to add year in drop down from past 2 year till present year in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried all sorts of code for this,but failed.
Please help me in filling years in drop down.
Thank you in advance.

```
    DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
    DropDownList2.Items.Add("--Year--");
    for (int i = 3;i>=0 ; i--)
   {
       Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Year . ToString();
       //DateTimeFormatInfo dinfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
       int year= int .Parse ( Label1. Text);
       Label1.Text = dinfo.GetMonthName(year);
        int year= DateTime.Now.Year;
        Label1.Text = year.ToString();        
        DropDownList2.Items.Add(year+i+ " ");
   }
```

Comment: *How* did it fail? Compile error? Runtime exception? Did you google it to understand what the error/exception is and why it's happening? It ran but something unexpected happened? What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? Did you try anything so far to fix the problem?

Comment: I think you need to set Label1.Text again.

Comment: Just to follow up on @tnw's comments, please do the following when asking a question here: 1) research the problem, 2) include all information ESPECIALLY error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with simplifying your code. This part is fine:

```
DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
DropDownList2.Items.Add("--Year--");
```

But there were several things wrong with your attempt. The first is that from 3 down to 0 stepping by 1 would give you the previous *three* years. So we can change your for-loop to step from 2 years ago, to 1 year ago, to now. `Label1` doesn't seem to serve any purpose, so let's eliminate that as well. You're basically left with a few lines that get the current year, loop for three iterations, and calculate a new year (converted to string) based on the counter in the loop, which is then added to your list:

```
var currentYear = DateTime.Today.Year;
for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
{    
    // Now just add an entry that's the current year minus the counter
    DropDownList2.Items.Add((currentYear - i).ToString());
}
```

So, with:

```
var currentYear = DateTime.Today.Year; // 2014
```

Let's loop:

- When `i == 2`, `(currentYear - i).ToString()` is "2012"
- When `i == 1`, `(currentYear - i).ToString()` is "2013"
- When `i == 0`, `(currentYear - i).ToString()` is "2014"

Comment: Thank you,it worked as per expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Based off the question, here is what I think your requirements are:

- You want to show the years from (CurrentYear) to (CurrentYear - 2) [past 2 years]
- The years should be in descending order.

You can use the following code to get the current year and 2 years before:

```
var years = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 2, 3)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

Then use it in your code:

```
DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
DropDownList2.Items.Add("--Year--");

foreach(var year in years)
{    
    DropDownList2.Items.Add(year.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Clear items:    
DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
// Add default item to the list
DropDownList1.Items.Add("--Year--");
// Start loop
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    // For each pass add an item
    // Add a number of years (negative, which will subtract) to current year
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-i).Year.ToString());
}
```

Sorry for no explanation earlier.

Comment: this would be a better answer if you explained why it works

Comment: To follow suit in the way this question's been going, Dmitri E's response would probably be "Magic".

Comment: oops, I am new here, pardon my short answers.

This line clears dropdownm menu
DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

This one adds new item
DropDownList1.Items.Add("--Year--");

next two are just a loop for the values going from zero to two. for each pass we are going to add a negative number of years and add the outcome to the items list of the drop down menu.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
string[] itens = new string[4] {
    "-- Year --",
    DateTime.Today.Year.ToString(),
    DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).Year.ToString(),
    DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2).Year.ToString()
};
DropDownList2.Items.AddRange(itens);
```

Or

```
DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
ListItem[] itens = new ListItem[4] {
    new ListItem("-- Year --"),
    new ListItem(DateTime.Today.Year.ToString()),
    new ListItem(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).Year.ToString()),
    new ListItem(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2).Year.ToString())
};
DropDownList2.Items.AddRange(itens);
```

Comment: Thanx for helping but this code is not working. Error:- The best overloaded match for AddRange() has some invalid argument.

Comment: Sorry for that. I've edited my reply.